# Preventing User from Continuing without adding data to a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a registration wizard in ASP.net that uses the `MultiView` control and I have multiple `View` Controls within it. An example of one `View` control can be seen below;

```
<asp:View ID="address_view" runat="server">
    <h1>Address:</h1>
<asp:Button ID="add_new_address" CssClass="blue" runat="server" Text="Add New Address" OnClick="add_new_address_Click" />
<div id="add_address_div" runat="server">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="address_dropdown_insert" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Home">Home Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Term">Term Time Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Mail">Mail Address</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="Business">Business Address</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList><br />
            Address 1:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_1TextBox" /><br />
            Address 2:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="address_2TextBox" /><br />
            Town/City:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="town_cityTextBox" /><br />
            County:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countyTextBox" /><br />
            PostCode:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="postcodeTextBox" /><br />
            Country:
            <asp:TextBox Text="" runat="server" ID="countryTextBox" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ID="InsertButton" OnClick="insert_address_button_Click" />
            <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" ID="Button4" OnClick="cancel_address_button_Click" /><br />
</div>
    <asp:ListView ID="address_list" runat="server" DataSourceID="user_address" DataKeyNames="address_id">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            // code here
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <br />
            <p>There are currently no addresses found, please click the button above to add a new address.</p>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            //code here
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            //code here
        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

<br />
    <asp:Button CommandName="NextView" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next" />
</asp:View>
```

The database table that the insert form inserts to is named `address`. It has the following fields

```
address_id
user_id
address_type
address_1
address_2
town_city
county
postcode
country
```

The `user_id` is pulled from another table called `users`.

I have the following C# to get the `user_id` of the current user who is logged in;

```
//get id of logged in user
        string user_id = Session["user_id"].ToString();
```

My question is, how can I prevent a user from continuing onto the next view when they click `Button1` if their `user_id` does not appear in the `address` table?

I'm fairly new to C# so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Presentationally you will want to disable Button1 until an address is entered. Initally your Button1 markup will include Enabled = "false"

```
<asp:Button CommandName="NextView" Enabled="false" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Next" />
```

Then within the insert_address_button_Click handler, after an address has been successfully added, enable the button like so:

```
protected void insert_address_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // ..insert the address. If successful, enable the "Next" button
    Button1.Enabled = true; 
}
```

That's a simple approach, but should do what you ask.

**EDIT:**
To address Button1's state in the user returns to the address view:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Enabled = address_list.Items.Any();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So, If student were to go back to the address view at the end of the registration wizard to edit the data that has been inserted previously the next button would not be enabled, is there anyway around this?

Comment: Indeed it would not. Then you can certainly check for a address applied to the user_id in session and set the enabled of Button1 accordingly. You'll have to forgive me that I don't recall the last time I used a MultiView control, but I suspect you can perform the check on Page_Load() and set Button1.Enabled as appropriate in there. Something like :

`Button1.Enabled = address_list.Items.Any();`

Which will resolve to true if your address_list has any items in it.